# Как можно отложить рисование на канвасе?

Tags: html5, canvas, матрицы

Я хочу нарисовать на канвасе "скелет" (последовательность взаимосвязанных прямоугольников каждый под определенным углом к родителю), я делаю это рекурсивно скелет начинается с тела и получается что обе руки уже поверх него, поэтому я хочу не рисовать его сразу, а сохранить все трансформациии канваса (смещения и повороты) при первом проходе, и затем рисовать каждую часть отдельно согласно z-order, задавая полученную ранее трансфомацию канвасу. Попытка сохранять (и аккумулировать значения поворотов и трансляций) ни к чему не приводит, я пробовал использовать матрицы, но не добился чтобы то, что я рисую потом было тем же что изначально. Вот сниппет отображающий суть проблемы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984114/javascript-saving-all-transformations-of-canvas-taking-into-account-the-save

Comment: а если зайти с другой стороны - начать отрисовку по z-индексу и в этот момент вычислять трансформации?

Comment: не уверен что это оптимальный вариант получиться больше проходов по дереву объектов, есть решение строить граф сцены, но я пока не реализовывал его.